# how to limit exit_frame in AS3 to only listener for stage

Tags: actionscript-3, frame, exit

Apparently I am not completely familiar with how EXIT_FRAME functions.

I was under the impression that it only listens to the exiting of stage frames like ENTER_FRAME

However it is triggering extra for each exiting of a frame movieclip with any actionscript on it.

Is there a way to limit this to only the stage like ENTER_FRAME?

Comment: Are you sure? Docs say otherwise: *Note: This event has neither a "capture phase" nor a "bubble phase", which means that event listeners must be added directly to any potential targets, whether the target is on the display list or not.*

Comment: Even `ENTER_FRAME` listeners are not listening to stage-only events, each independent object on the display list can have its own enterframe listener. To make an object not receive an enterframe event, one needed to just remove it from the display list. The same should apply to exit frame event.

Comment: @Vesper Incorrect about display list attachment. The docs explicitly state the opposite and I have code that does not requite things attached to display list yet rely on ENTER_FRAME event: https://bitbucket.org/thydmitry/ru.delimiter/src/022a2f6fcb1c6752a76575df95b117fbca861328/classes/ru/delimiter/events/Chronos.as?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: @Organis Hmm nice code. However this question means that there is some flaw in exit_frame event parsing, or OP added two entities of a listener to some of his objects.

Comment: @Vesper Yep. The problem **should not** be the concept of EXIT_FRAME, which is supposed to happen once per frame per object, but - you might have guessed right - multiple subscriptions or something.

Comment: there is only one eventlistener added to stage, no other instances exist,
exit_frame triggers anytime ANY object exits a frame containing action script, even a simple line of `gotoAndPlay(1)`

try it for yourself

Comment: @Koden, please provide us with MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), expected result description and observed result description.